# Did a leaked email reveal that NATO and France had Gaddafi killed to prevent the release of a new gold-backed currency?

Tags: politics, hillary-clinton, email, gaddafi

"Supposedly", the leaked Hillary emails exposed NATO and France was behind taking down Gaddafi in Libya due to the "gold backed" dinar they were about to release.

Based on the article [Libyan Oil, Gold, and Qaddafi: The Strange Email Sidney Blumenthal Sent Hillary Clinton In 2011](https://news.vice.com/en_us/article/gy9d49/libyan-oil-gold-and-qaddafi-the-strange-email-sidney-blumenthal-sent-hillary-clinton-in-2011):

> ...While France's then-President Nicolas Sarkozy publicly said he wished to free the Libyan people from tyranny, Blumenthal's memo argues that he was driven by a cocktail of less lofty incentives, including a desire for Libyan oil, and a fear that Qaddafi secretly planned to use his vast supply of gold to displace France's primacy in the region...

What official documents can one reference to solidify these claims? Or is this just another unconfirmed "conspiracy"?

Comment: You're going to need to give a link or source to where this claim is being made, otherwise the question might not pass muster as being a notable claim to be evaluated.

Comment: updated with a link.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to say, I anticipate answers or comments based on the fact that this article is about having ulterior economic motives for pushing regime change in the Middle East (not exactly a new thing for western nations), and you are making it sound like the intent was for NATO to kill Ghaddafi, specifically, and there's nothing anywhere in that article that indicates that.

Comment: Sidney Blumenthal had a lot of opinions, but he wasn't a government official or even particularly well-informed.  Speculations in his emails have about the same weight as similar ones any random person might post in the comment section of a newspaper article..

Comment: Along the same lines, the article that you posted with the claim has its own doubts about the theory.  What would you consider to be an answer that you find acceptable?

Comment: So there is an alleged email that has someone citing 'unknown sources' that are claiming a particular motive for something? Seems pretty tenuous, even if the Vice report is completely true and reliable.

Comment: Did he even have a vast supply of gold in the first place?

Comment: @GordonM from what i've read online, it was apparently only 143 tons of gold, worth approximately $5Bil.  I highly doubt you're gonna start a gold backed currency that would disrupt the market with $5 Billion dollars

Comment: Well if this is the case it failed. Russia and China are about to do this... Encouraged by the US's abuse of SWIFT etc. It might be a little harder to prevent that. Given that China has nukes... And a modern standing army many times bigger than any other country.